# phantomjs onResourceRequested - block third-party connections

Tags: javascript, regex, phantomjs

I have a function:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function (requestData, networkRequest)
{
console.log('\[REQUEST URL] : ' + requestData.url );

var match = requestData.url.match
(
/advert.com/ | /misc.org/|
/chat.com/| /stat.net/|
/https?:\/\/.+?\.css$/g 
);
if (match != null)
{
console.log('\[BLOCKED REQUEST URL] : ' + requestData.url );
networkRequest.cancel();
}
return;
};
```

This func should block all requests to third-party domains and preventing css loading. But it not works. I lost 20 minutes here, tried different combinations.. I think my regexp knowledge is bad at this time. 
Sorry, my indentation with tabs does not works here.

Comment: Try this combination:
var match = requestData.url.match(/advert.com|misc.org|chat.com|stat.net|https?:\/\/.+?\.css$/);

Comment: Thank you! Your variant works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination:

```
var match = requestData.url.match(/advert.com|misc.org|chat.com|stat.net|https?:\/\/.+?\.css$/);
```

– a-bobkov